# How to insert two lines of text after every line? plus an added line

Tags: notepad++

```
    63888501.txt
    36346246.txt
    36026700.txt
    53846004.txt
    57910034.txt
    45585184.txt
    11389311.txt
    47389379.txt
    63389410.txt
    23392487.txt
```

Output should be:

```
    notepad.exe 63888501.txt
    taskkill /f /im ffs.exe 
    notepad.exe one.txt
    notepad.exe 36346246.txt
    taskkill /f /im ffs.exe
    notepad.exe one.txt
    notepad.exe 36026700.txt
    taskkill /f /im ffs.exe
    notepad.exe one.txt
    notepad.exe 53846004.txt
    taskkill /f /im ffs.exe
    notepad.exe one.txt
    notepad.exe 57910034.txt
    taskkill /f /im ffs.exe
    notepad.exe one.txt
    notepad.exe 45585184.txt
    taskkill /f /im ffs.exe
    notepad.exe one.txt
    notepad.exe 11389311.txt
    taskkill /f /im ffs.exe
    notepad.exe one.txt
    notepad.exe 47389379.txt
    taskkill /f /im ffs.exe
    notepad.exe one.txt
    notepad.exe 63389410.txt
    taskkill /f /im ffs.exe
    notepad.exe one.txt
    notepad.exe 23392487.txt
    taskkill /f /im ffs.exe
    notepad.exe one.txt
```

Comment: Why to choose that approach. Use `for /L` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the line separator characters with the additional text as required.  There's a few ways to accomplish this but I would first:

- Go **View** -> **Show Symbols** -> **Show all characters**

You should be able to see if the lines are separated by:

- only a *Linefeed* (`LF`) - which can be search/replaced with `\n`, ***or***,
- a *Carriage Return plus Linefeed* (<kbd>`CR`</kbd><kbd>`LF`</kbd>) - which can be search/replaced with `\r\n`.

> Once you know what kind of character(s) you're going to be replacing you can toggle  "all characters" again to hide them (the same way you showed them) although it's sometimes handy to see where there are tabs vs spaces etc, if any.

---

Assuming it's just Linefeeds between (and assuming that the **indent** in your example is **un**intentional):

1. Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the **Replace** dialog.
2. In the "**Search Mode**" options, choose <kbd>Extended (\n, \r, \t....)</kbd>
3. In "**Find what**" enter:
   `\n`
4. In "**Replace with** enter:
   `\ntaskkill /f /im ffs.exe\nnotepad.exe one.txt\nnotepad.exe` ← <sub>(there is a space after ".exe")</sub>
5. Click <kbd>**Replace All**</kbd>.

---

If something goes wrong, click anywhere in the file (outside of the Replace dialog) and hit Ctrl+Z to undo try again.

If your file was separated with **CR+LF** instead of just **LF**, use `\r\n` instead of the 4 `\n`'s.

With some practice N++ can be extremely handy for manipulating text or code in this manner, and more-so with the addition of [N++ RegEx](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions) rules/replacements.

[image]

Comment: The first line is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Replace` dialog <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>:

```
   Find what: ^(\s+)(.*)$
Replace with: \1notepad.exe \2\r\n\1taskkill /f /im ffs.exe\r\n\1notepad.exe one.txt
Search Mode
(*) Regular expression
```

- `^(\s+)` line starts with one or more space characters (referenced as `\1`)
- `(.*)$` any amount of characters until the end of the line (referenced as `\2`)

I used Windows linebreaks `\r\n` (carriage return/line feed), for Unix linebreaks use `\n` (line feed).

Then use `Find Next` and `Replace` or `Replace All`

Answer (score 0):

This works with any kind of linebreak:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+(\R)`
- Replace with: `notepad.exe $0taskill /f /im ffs.exe$1notepad.exe one.txt$1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  .+            # 1 or more any character but newline
  (\R)          # group 1, capture the line break whatever it is (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]